# Null Pointer Exception in Java when using String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a piece of code where the program compares the value of two arrays of strings. I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, even though I initialized both arrays. Here is the relevant code:

```
String[] functions=new String [inputs+1];
int funCounter=0;
for (int a=0;a<2;a++)
{
    for (int b=0;b<2;b++)
    {
        if (tokenizedString[b].equals(keywords[a])&&keywords[a].equals("add"))
        {
            System.out.println("Yay");
            functions[funCounter]="add";
            funCounter++;
        }
        }
    }
```

This is where I inialize tokenizedString:

```
String[] tokenizedString;
    tokenizedString=new String[2];
```

tokenizedString is added to a Scanner in stream here:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input," ");
```

And here is where I initialize keywords:

```
String[] keywords;
    keywords=new String[2];
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You've initialized `tokenizedString`, but have you initialized `tokenizedString[0]` and `tokenizedString[1]`?

Comment: Using user input from the Scanner class.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You need to show all the relevant code, and putting values in your arrays is certainly relevant to fixing an NPE.  If your error is in your initialization code, we're not going to be able to help if we can't see it. It would also be nice if you would mark the line in your code which is throwing the exception.

Comment: What is the content of `keywords`? Did you assign any values as elements of `tokenizedString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are accessing tokenizedString[n], the string array will give you the nth element. If the nth element is not initialized, for object arrays it will be defaulted to null.

A better way to avoid null checks in this case will be to switch places of the string values if you are sure that the other one will never be null. So instead of:

```
 tokenizedString[b].equals(keywords[a])
```

use:

```
 keywords[a].equals(tokenizedString[b])
```

Comment: Even safer would be something like `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils#equals()`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll check it as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: [Approving this, Yoda does not](http://blue-walrus.com/2010/11/reverse-equals-in-java-a-dangerous-technique/)

Comment: @azurefrog what is that, and how do I do it?

Comment: @APCoding http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html